# (React Native) redirect login and logout to different screen respectively

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am trying to redirect screen when the following action are taken, first when I log in I want to redirect to `account screen` and also when I logout it should redirect to `login screen`, currently when I login it's take me to home screen and when I logout it also goes to `home screen`.

In my `AuthNavigator` I have the following screens `Home`, `Listing`, `Login`

In my `AppNavigator` I have the following screens `Home`, `Listing`, `Account`

Both `AuthNavigator` and `AppNavigator` have the below stack navigator

```
    <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
        initialRouteName={ 'Home'}  
    >
        ... screen
   <Stack.Navigator />
```

**Context.js**

```
import React  from 'react';
const AuthContext = React.createContext();
export default AuthContext;
```

**App.js**

```
import AuthContext from './context';

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
          { user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator/> }
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**Account.js**

```
const Panel = ({navigation}) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Name {user.name} </Text>
      <Text>Email {user.email} </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Login.js**

```
const handleSubmit = async ( { email, password } ) =>{
    const response = await axios.post(userLogin, 
    { 
        email, 
        password,
    })
    .then((response) => { 
        const user = response.data;
        authContext.setUser(user);
    })
    .catch(error => { 
        console.log(error);
    }); 
}
```

How can I route or redirect to `account screen` after I sign in and to `login screen` after I logout
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you duplicate `Home, Listing` in both navigators?

You should have one navigator for them, and another one only for Login & Account screens.

AppNavigator: HomeScreen, ListingScreen

And on the Listing screen, a navigate event to the AuthNavigator to display Login or Account screen

AuthNavigator: LoginScreen, AccountScreen

where you will have the check,
if Authenticated  -> AccountScreen
else -> LoginScreen

Comment: I duplicate home and listing because I want to be able to have access to the screen(home and listing) after I login to my account. I dont understand 'AuthNavigator to display Login or Account screen'

Comment: I check if user is set to access `<AppNavigator />`  after login `{ user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator/> }`

Answer (score 0):

I use two different Stack Navigator
One is for Authentication where login and Create Screens are and the other is for authenticated screens. If the user is not logged it goes back to AuthStackNavigator.
Here is a code example... :)

```
    <NavigationContainer>
            {
                isAuthenticated ? <StackNavigator/> : <AuthStackNavigator/>
            }
   </NavigationContainer>
```

1. *isAuthenticated === true  ----> Show StackNavigator*
2. *isAuthenticated === false ----> Show AuthStackNavigator*